# AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, datetime, время

Пишу telegram бот на python, и код выдаёт ошибку
`AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'`

```
def remove_task(message):
    task_date = message.text
    try:
        task_date = datetime.strptime(task_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
        if task_date in tasks:
            del tasks[task_date]
            bot.reply_to(message, 'Task deleted successfully!')
        else:
            bot.reply_to(message, 'No task found for that date.')
    except ValueError:
        bot.reply_to(message, 'Invalid date format. Please try again.')
```

Тоже самое кстати с datetime.now

```
def check_tasks():
    today = datetime.now().date()

    if today in tasks:
        task_description = tasks[today]
        bot.send_message('<USER_CHAT_ID>', f'Task for today: {task_description}')
```

Comment: `datetime.datetime.strptime` или `from datetime import datetime`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Должно быть у тебя `datetime` не является тем чем должен

Рабочий пример:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

task_date = '2022-12-12'

task_date = dt.strptime(task_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
```